# Strong parameters definition issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

Employee controller has the following definition for params. Positions attribute seems init correctly.

```
def employee_params
  params.fetch(:employee, {}).permit(
    :note,
    positions_attributes: [:id, :branch_id , :department_id, :employee_id],
    :work_type)
end
```

The error I am getting is the following:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put not enclosed in `{}` hash, it's only possible if this is the last parameter of the method. This is not the case in your example, so you should change your code a little bit:

```
def employee_params
  params.fetch(:employee, {}).permit(:note, :work_type,
                                     positions_attributes: [:id, :branch_id , :department_id, :employee_id])
end
```

Comment: I tried that, but in that case positions in employee model are not initialized.

Comment: @DenisBesic so you have more than this problem, probably. Like: Are you sure you have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :positions`

Comment: Yes I have. I think I covered the basics. : class Employee < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :positions
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :positions